# Is there a difference between the terms "data integrity" and "data quality"?

Tags: database, data-integrity, data-quality

I was asked this question in an interview today, and didn't know how to answer.

Can anyone provide an insight as to the differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Data integrity](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/data-integrity.html):** The accuracy and consistency of stored data, indicated by an absence of any alteration in data between two updates of a data record. Data integrity is imposed within a database at its design stage through the use of standard rules and procedures, and is maintained through the use of error checking and validation routines.

**[Data quality](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/data-quality)** is a perception or an assessment of data's fitness to serve its purpose in a given context.

Aspects of data quality include:

```
Accuracy
Completeness
Update status
Relevance
Consistency across data sources
Reliability
Appropriate presentation
Accessibility
```

Comment: -1 On the assumption this is copied and pasted from elsewhere. Edit: Yep [Data Quality](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/data-quality) and [Data Integrity](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/data-integrity.html)

Comment: Yes, he actually mentioned the sources, so it indeed is copied from somewhere else :)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth - Only after I left my comment, it was unattributed previously! Check the timing on the edit history. And it is still completely in violation of copyright [`Reproduction of all or part of this dictionary and/or of any other content on this site, in any format, without our written consent is strictly prohibited.`](http://www.businessdictionary.com/disclaimer.php)

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is wrt ETL testing :
Data integrity(orphan check) - Check if the newly added column/ existing column has a parent which is null or blank.

Data quality (percent null check) - This check is performed only when a new column is added to the table .